# Error code - 403 while posting XML data to ASP.Net application form due to AWS Load balancer

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I created an ASP.Net application that accepts XML data as input and responds with an XML response. When  I execute in localhost and IP address the application works fine. But when I assign it to the domain name and add AWS Load balancer it is not getting the output as expected.

Here are the Application responses,

Output on Localhost and IP address,

```
Request URL: http://10.xx.xx.xx:8080/xmlpost.aspx
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.xx.xx.xx:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 5511451
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Oct 2021 08:42:52 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   # Note here
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 263
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 10.xx.xx.xx:8080
Origin: http://10.xx.xx.xx:8080
Referer: http://10.xx.xx.xx:8080/xmlpost.aspx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XRequest>
    <RequestType>CompanyList</RequestType>
    <AuthenticationToken>XXXX-KKKK-GGGG-BBBB</AuthenticationToken>
</XRequest>
xmlResponse:
```

Output on the domain

```
Request URL: dev.mysite.com/xmlpost.aspx
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-length: 520
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 11 Oct 2021 08:38:27 GMT
server: awselb/2.0             # I think here is the problem
:authority: dev.mysite.com
:method: POST
:path: /xmlpost.aspx
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 263
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gyyjjtazrjja5hwqpvjkdecc
origin: https://dev.mysite.com
referer: https://dev.mysite.com/xmlpost.aspx
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XRequest>
    <RequestType>CompanyList</RequestType>
    <AuthenticationToken>XXXX-KKKK-GGGG-BBBB</AuthenticationToken>
</XRequest>
xmlResponse:
```

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;


public partial class XMLPost : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("DEFAULT");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        String xmlin = Request.Params["xml"] + "";
        String uri = "";

        if (xmlin.IndexOf("<RequestType>CompanyList</RequestType>") > -1) {
            log.Debug("Logout section");
            
            uri = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebRoot"] + "CompanyFeed.aspx";
            
            
        } else if (xmlin.IndexOf("<RequestType>CompanyJobs</RequestType>") > -1) {
            uri = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebRoot"] + "CompanyFeed.aspx";
        }
        

        if ((Request.Params["xml"] + "").Length > 0) { 
        
            WebRequest req = null;
            WebResponse rsp = null;
            try {

                req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                
                // req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
                req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
                req.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;";     // content type
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
                writer.WriteLine(Request.Params["xml"]+"");
                writer.Close();
                
                // Send the data to the webserver
                
                rsp = req.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
                String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                xmlResponse.Value = xmlData;

            } catch(WebException webEx) {
                xmlResponse.Value = webEx.ToString();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                xmlResponse.Value = ex.ToString();
            } finally {
                
                if(req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
                if(rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();

            } // end try
        
        } // end if

    } // page load

}
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="D:\logfiles\mysite_logs.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="APP_MSSQL_SCHEMA" value="dbo"/>

    <add key="APP_MSSQL_CONN_STR" value="Data Source=mysite.rds.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=Mydb;User Id=admin;Password=admin;"/>
    <add key="AuthenticationToken" value="XXXX-KKKK-GGGG-BBBB"/>
    <add key="WebRoot" value="https://dev.mysite.com/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Login.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You're getting a [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) - what is your authentication code?

Comment: I am using "Windows" authentication mode. If I submit the form with a normal text it works but when I use XML it does not works

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - can you please provide your controller code?

Comment: I have the code and web config file.